# How to redirect a page using onclick event in php?

Tags: php, html

I tried with this code but it's not working,

```
<input type="button" value="Home" class="homebutton" id="btnHome" onClick="<?php header("Location: /index.php"); ?>" />
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I see that this is your first post! If answers are helpful, you can vote them up with the arrow. It is good to pick the most helpful answer and accept it with the checkmark! This will let other people with the same issue know what answer best helped you solve your issue.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't use php code client-side. You need to use javascript.

```
<input type="button" value="Home" class="homebutton" id="btnHome" 
onClick="document.location.href='some/page'" />
```

However, you really shouldn't be using inline js (like onclick here). Study about this here: https://www.google.com/search?q=Why+is+inline+js+bad%3F

Here's a clean way of doing this: **[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/AgajOmi/1/edit)**

**Markup:**

```
<button id="myBtn">Redirect</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var btn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.location.href = 'some/page';
});
```

**If you need to write in the location with php:**

```
  <button id="myBtn">Redirect</button>
  <script>
    var btn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      document.location.href = '<?php echo $page; ?>';
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do people keep confusing php and javascript?

PHP is **SERVER SIDE**
JAVASCRIPT (like onclick) is **CLIENT SIDE**

You will have to use *just* javascript to redirect. Otherwise if you want PHP involved you can use an AJAX call to log a hit or whatever you like to send back a URL or additional detail.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
    <input type="button" value="Home" class="homebutton" id="btnHome" onClick="Javascript:window.location.href = 'http://www.website.com/index.php';" />
```

window.location.href example:

```
 window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'; //Will take you to Google.
```

window.open() example:

```
     window.open('http://www.google.com'); //This will open Google in a new window.
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using `onclick` which is javascript event.
there is two ways

Javascript

```
<input type="button" value="Home" class="homebutton" id="btnHome" 
onClick="window.location = 'http://google.com'" />
```

Or PHP

create another page as redirect.php and put

```
<?php header('location : google.com') ?>
```

and insert this link on any page within the same directory

```
<a href="redirect.php">google<a/>
```

hope this helps its simplest!!